# While and if looping with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having problems to understand where is my mistake. I'm trying to get an input from the user > if "yes" - show some data from a DataFrame > if "no" keep going with the program.

Inside of if "yes" there's another question "Do you want more data?", and once again > if "yes" keep showing > if "no" leave both loops and continue with the program.

```
def display_data(df):
        n = 0
        raw_in = input('\nWould you like to see some raw data? yes or no.\n').lower()
        while raw_in in ['yes','no']:
            if raw_in == 'yes':
                raw_data = df.iloc[n:n+5,:]
                n += 5
                print(raw_data)
                raw_in = input('\nMore data? yes or no.\n').lower()
                if raw_in not in ['yes','no']:
                    print('\nInvalid option.\n')
                    display_data(df)
                else:
                    pass
```

That's what I've tried. I keep changing from `while` to `if` or their position, but I don't find the solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You don't appear to make an attempt to get a second batch of data. Where is the `while` loop?

Comment: @roganjosh thank you for responding. I've changed too many times the code, that I forgot I was using only IFs this time. I already modified it. I want to know how to make work that double loop

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need your `while` condition to check for `'no'`. Seems that you want `'no'` to stop the execution. Since you only need `while raw_in == 'yes'`, you won't need the subsequent if statement either. Also, `else, pass` doesn't really serve a purpose.

```
def display_data(df):
    n = 0
    raw_in = input('\nWould you like to see some raw data? yes or no.\n').lower()
    while raw_in == 'yes':
        raw_data = df.iloc[n:n+5,:]
        n += 5
        print(raw_data)
        raw_in = input('\nMore data? yes or no.\n').lower()
        if raw_in not in ['yes','no']:
            print('\nInvalid option.\n')
            display_data(df)
```